# jsf - intercept when user departs page

Tags: jsf, page-lifecycle

I have the following 3 simple pages in a JSF app.

```
index.html
start.html
confirmSuccess.thml
```

start.html is a simple form, with a "GO!" button and a html link back to index.html.  When the user clicks GO! it kicks of a transaction in the backing bean. If this fails, I want start.html form redisplayed, but with an error explaining failure. So, I have an error flag set in my backing bean, and the error display is managed using rendered="" attribute.

Simple, right?

So, how do I handle the case where the user then clicks the html link to index.html, and from index.html clicks the link back to start.html, or simply clicks back.  That is, how do I clear intercept that user has departed the start page, and clear the error flag so I know second time around that I don't need to display the error.

Is this possible without getting deep into the bowels of JSF lifecycle management?

**Note** The 3 pages listed is a gross oversimplification of my webapp, in reality, there multiple pages a user can go to from start.html, so I don't want to have a solution where I need to track the page someone arrives at to clear flags for start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're transferring request scoped data around in a session scoped bean. Make the bean which holds request scoped data **request** scoped and instruct the browser to [not cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407) the dynamic pages so that it is forced to re-request the page from the webserver instead of from its history.

That said, I'd rather use a combination of [`FacesContext#addMessage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#addMessage%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.application.FacesMessage%29) and [`<h:messages/>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/messages.html) to display errors. You can use an `clientId` of `null` to denote global message. They are in turn already request based so that you don't need to hassle with a *flag* to render/unrender an error display.

E.g.

```
public void submit() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Error!"));
}
```

with

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks - You're right about the request/session scoped root cause. In any case, I'll go for the <h:messages/> idea.